# angularjs listen on keypresses anywhere, react in controllers differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is this:

I have a webpage that lists stuff in a table. Naturally, there is pagination, which I'd like to traverse using keyboard arrows.

At the same time, a user can click on any record in the table, which will open a modal dialog (from twitter-bootstrap), which also contains a next/previous record functionality, currently only available via buttons. I'd like to be able to control that with keyboard arrows aswell, but if the modal dialog is opened, the main table pages are not flipped.

I have tried using $document.bind in the main page controller, but it doesn't work correctly, the variable listener is not being triggered.

Example code for that is:

```
<script>
    function Controller($scope, $document)
    {
        $scope.page = 1;

        $scope.$watch('page', function()
        {
            console.log('this is not logged on key press');
        });

        $document.bind('keyup', function(event)
        {
            if (event.which === 37) // <-
            {
                if ($scope.page === 1)
                {
                    return;
                }

                $scope.page--;
                console.log('this is logged');
            }
            else if (event.which === 39) // ->
            {
                if ($scope.page === $scope.numPages)
                {
                    return;
                }

                $scope.page++;
                console.log('this is logged');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Controller">
</div>
```

The other thing I've tried that is only for the modal dialog is binding `<div class="modal-body" ng-keyup="changeRecord($event)">`, but that, for some reason, only works while the focus is on the input field in the modal dialog. When I click on anywhere else in the modal dialog, the `changeRecord` function is not called anymore, which is weird to say the least.

What would be the correct solutions to this problem?

I certainly don't like binding on `$document`, it just doesn't feel right.

Edit:

here's my current solution that works exactly as intended, but is kind of hackish: http://pastebin.com/ZiK8Mt8e
If you can suggest anything that is better and just as short as this, go ahead. I would certainly not want to use another library just for handling literally 2 keyboard buttons.

Comment: You might want to have a look at managing your keyboard shortcuts using a library like [angular-hotkeys](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/), rather than using `$document.bind` and checking for the key codes directly.

Comment: Try to call $apply in bind maybe that bind it's just the same as jQuery one.

Comment: @jcubic did that about an hour after I created the question. That didn't solve the whole problem though. Here's my (at the moment) final solution: http://pastebin.com/ZiK8Mt8e, which is certainly not ideal, but it's the shortest I could make it without using additional libraries, for which I have no need.